# Delphi check if two Pointer targeting the same memory location

Tags: pointers, delphi, memory

I'm looking for a way to check if two pointers are addressing the same memory location I thought I could check the two pointer adresses but they seems to be different. So how can I check if a Pointer targets to the same memory location as another?

```
procedure TForm2.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   tmp : Tobject;
   p1,p2 :Pointer;
begin
  tmp:=self;
  p1:=@self;
  p2:=@tmp;

  if(p1=p2) then begin
    ShowMessage('true');
  end else begin
    ShowMessage('false');
  end;
end;
```

I'm using Embarcadero Delphi 11 but this should not make any difference here.

Comment: Your code is wrong. Seems you misunderstood the concept in Delphi: Object variables like "tmp" or "self" are already pointers. Taking the address using the "@" operator takes the address of the variable, not the value.

Comment: "*I thought I could check the two pointer adresses*" - you can. That is exactly how you compare pointers. "*but they seems to be different*" - because in your example, they really are pointing at different memory locations. `tmp` is a pointer that is pointing to the same object that `self` is pointing at. `@self` is the address of the `self` pointer itself, not the address of the object that `self` is pointing at. `@tmp` is the address of the `tmp` pointer itself, not the address of the object that `tmp` is pointing at. Change `p1:=@self; p2:=@tmp;` to `p1:=self; p2:=tmp;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, thats exactly the same what came in my mind tonight ;-) Sometimes the easy parts are the difficult.